# When sending WW-Authenticate header of digest authentication with SHA-256 with Java Servlet, the client side does not return the result

Tags: java, http, tomcat, curl, sha

I am developing a Web API that performs Digest authentication, but when I set the message digest algorithm to SHA-256, the client side seems to crash.
Is there something wrong with the server-side implementation?

Language: Java, Server: Tomcat7.0
OS: Windows 10 for both server and client

Digest authentication does not use tomcat's web.xml, server.xml, or tomcat-users.xml settings, but implements sending WWW-Authenticate header and receiving Authorization header in Servlet.
At this time, if MD5 is used as the algorithm of the digest, authentication will succeed, but if you change to SHA-256 because it is deprecated, the client side will not return the result after sending the WW-Authenticate header .

WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm = "example.com", qop = auth, nonce = "f5d6eeccc66664731c72e3300d3dfadf", opaque = "56b2ea6d037b522661a3719ec48b7d9a", algorithm = SHA-256

- Successful when algorithm = MD5

(In the case of browser)

An error occurs in Http status 401 without displaying the dialog for entering the user and password.
Looking at the communication status with the developer tools, it seems that WWW-Authenticate: is received, but it does not seem to generate Authorization header.

(curl command)

curl -v -k --digest --use r "user: password" "url"

After receiving the WWW-Authenticate header, curl exits with an out of memory message

Comment: Which version of `curl` are you using?

Comment: I am using curl 7.55.1(windows).

Comment: If one of the answers solves your problem, you can mark them as accepted (the big check mark ✔ near the answer).

Answer (score 1):

The addition of other hash algorithms beyond MD5 to the DIGEST authentication scheme is rather recent (2015, cf. [RFC 7616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7616)).

The first version of cURL to support it was published two years later (version 7.57.0, cf. [changelog](https://curl.se/changes.html#7_57_0)).

Therefore you need to upgrade your version of cURL.

**Remark**: Instead of implementing the DIGEST algorithm from scratch, it might be better to modify Tomcat's [`DigestAuthenticator`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/DigestAuthenticator.html) to support RFC 7616 and send a PR on [github](https://github.com/apache/tomcat).

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

After updating curl to version 7.78, I tried again.

Next time,

"schannel: InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_QOP_NOT_SUPPORTED (0x8009030A)"

I got the error!!(Windows10)

Comment: You stumbled upon [this issue](https://curl.se/docs/knownbugs.html#SHA_256_digest_not_supported_in). You need to use a version which does not use SSPI, e.g. those on [paehl.de](https://www.paehld.de/open_source/?CURL_7.78.0) (linked from the [official download page](https://curl.se/download.html)).

Comment: "https://www.paehld.de/open_source/?CURL_7.78.0"

I downloaded "Download SSH2 and SSL version" and updated curl.
The error no longer occurs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Digest access authentication - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication#Overview):

> However, as of July 2021, none of popular browsers, including Firefox[[1](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=472823)] and Chrome,[[2](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1160478)] support SHA-256 as the hash function.